# Merge tags "rhotic" and "rhoticity"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Not sure why [rhotic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhotic) and [rhoticity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhoticity) are separate tags.  One should at least be a synonym of the other.

Comment: Apparently there are currently only 4 questions tagged ***rhoticity***, so it's not surprising I haven't gained the minimum 5 points required to cast a synonym vote. Personally I think it's not really worth having at all - we should just edit all 4 to match the other 28 questions tagged ***rhotic*** and be done with it. I can't see why anyone would have wanted to type the extra three letters, and I don't see any meaningful distinction in context (besides which, if there *were* a difference we shouldn't be thinking about merging them in the first place).

Comment: I just suggested tag edits to move the 4 `rhoticity` questions to `rhotic`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crisis averted ;)

Per FumbleFingers's comment: Retagged the four [rhoticity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhoticity) questions to use [rhotic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhotic).

Now go vote on [Tag Synonyms on Low Use Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80423/241697) so we never have to go through this exercise again!

Answer (score 3):

I’ve made these tags synonyms now.